# Find the difference between multiple date intervals from one in java

Tags: java, date, intervals, difference

I want to subtract the master interval A from the given interval set B, C and D to obtain the output of exactly non overlapping date interval.
B, C and D intervals can be of several years or months. However A will be of 90 days only.

```
A = ["2015-01-01 00:00", "2015-01-20 00:00"]
B = ["2015-01-05 00:00", "2015-01-10 00:00"]
C = ["2015-01-11 00:00", "2015-01-14 00:00"]
D = ["2015-01-19 00:00", "2015-01-25 00:00"]

1                  A               20
|----------------------------------|
    |---------|   |----------|   |------------|
    5    B    9  11    C    14  19    D      25
```

Desirable Output:
{1,2,3,4,10,15,16,17,18}

```
1   4         10         15     18
|---|         |          |------|
```

What i have done so far?

```
I have iterated all the entries from A(1-20) in a list and all other entries B,C and D in another list and find out A-(B+C+D).
This is surely the longest way because the duration can be of several years.
```

Please suggest quickest way to do this.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: FInd out about `java.time`...

Comment: how comes the desired output starts at `2` and not at `1`?  How comes the first interval ends at `4` at not at `5`? Why isn't second interval from `10` to `11`? ... and I don't know the *quickest way* (probably not asking in forum)  :-|

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger,  yes, it will start from 1. Need to find exact non-overlapping so  not included 5, 9, 11, 14, 19

Comment: @AshvinSharma - I have included what i have done so far in my question description.

Comment: @deHaar - Not clear what you want to say?

Comment: Your lines of data do not match your diagram. The line `B` is defined as 5 to 10, and you draw 5-9. This is inconsistent with the next line `C` going from 11-14 and you draw 11-14. Also, notice the last section of may Answer discussing Half-Open versus Fully-Closed definitions of span-of-time.

Comment: @PoojaVerma See the answer given by @LHCHIN, it makes use of the package `java.time` (`LocalDateTime` is a class from that package). What I wanted to tell you is: Read about how to use that package ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that all the given intervals will be in the same month, and then you can use following code snippet to mark each day that belongs to which interval and store the result to an array. Finally, you can know the non overlapping intervals by traversing this array.

**Code snippet**

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
String[] a = {"2015-01-01 00:00", "2015-01-20 00:00"};
String[] b = {"2015-01-05 00:00", "2015-01-10 00:00"};
String[] c = {"2015-01-11 00:00", "2015-01-14 00:00"};
String[] d = {"2015-01-19 00:00", "2015-01-25 00:00"};

String days[] = new String[31];
Arrays.fill(days, "X");

Arrays.fill(days,
        LocalDateTime.parse(a[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth()-1,
        LocalDateTime.parse(a[1], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth(),
        "A");

Arrays.fill(days,
        LocalDateTime.parse(b[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth()-1,
        LocalDateTime.parse(b[1], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth(),
        "B");

Arrays.fill(days,
        LocalDateTime.parse(c[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth()-1,
        LocalDateTime.parse(c[1], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth(),
        "C");

Arrays.fill(days,
        LocalDateTime.parse(d[0], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth()-1,
        LocalDateTime.parse(d[1], DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)).getDayOfMonth(),
        "D");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(days));
```

**Console output**

> [A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, B, B, C, C, C, C, A, A, A, A, D, D, D, D, D, D, D, X, X, X, X, X, X]

Comment: Intervals can range from several years.

Comment: @Pooja Verma OK, then what the expected output looks like?

Comment: {1,2,3,4,10,15,16,17,18} Reference from the question description

Comment: @Pooja Verma But as you said, interval A may cross may months such as 2019-01-31 to 2019-04-01, will the output show days only?

Comment: yes, It can cross years as well. Output should be days only.

Answer (score 2):

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

The *ThreeTen-Extra* library adds the functionality of the *java.time* framework built into Java 8 and later.

This library offers two classes to represent a span-of-time attached to the timeline:

- `Interval` represents a pair of moments, two `Instant` objects.
- `LocalDateRange` represents a pair of dates, two `LocalDate` objects.

Both classes include handy methods for comparison such as `abuts`, `contains`, `equals`, `intersection`, `overlaps`, `span`, and `union`.

## Define ranges

Define your target span.

```
LocalDateRange target = LocalDateRange.of( 
    LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-01" ) ,
    LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-20" ) ,
) ;
```

Define your other ranges.

```
List < LocalDateRange > ranges = List.of(
        LocalDateRange.of( LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-05" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-10" ) ) ,
        LocalDateRange.of( LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-11" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-14" ) ) ,
        LocalDateRange.of( LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-19" ) , LocalDate.parse( "2015-01-25" ) )
);
```

## Stream dates

There likely is a more clever way to do this that may be more efficient. But in this approach we simply stream all the dates of the target range. For each date we ask if any of the ranges contain that date.

Streaming the dates of a range looks like this one-line.

```
List < LocalDate > dates = target.stream().filter( localDate -> this.rangesDoNotContain( ranges , localDate ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

That line calls a custom method we wrote.

```
private boolean rangesDoNotContain ( List < LocalDateRange > ranges , LocalDate localDate )
{
    for ( LocalDateRange range : ranges )
    {
        if ( range.contains( localDate ) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Results:

> dates.toString(): [2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03, 2015-01-04, 2015-01-10, 2015-01-14, 2015-01-15, 2015-01-16, 2015-01-17, 2015-01-18]

## Stream ranges

We can make further use of streams to shrink this code. By calling [`Stream::nonMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) with `ranges.stream()` we can eliminate the `rangesDoNotContain` method we wrote.

```
List < LocalDate > list = target.stream().filter( localDate -> ranges.stream().noneMatch( range -> range.contains( localDate ) ) ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

Let's wrap that code to make it more readable. And let's make the type of the arguments explicit.

```
List < LocalDate > list = 
        target
        .stream()
        .filter( 
            ( LocalDate localDate ) -> ranges
                                       .stream()
                                       .noneMatch(  
                                           ( LocalDateRange range ) -> range.contains( localDate ) 
                                       ) 
        )
        .collect( Collectors.toList() )
;
```

Same results.

> [2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03, 2015-01-04, 2015-01-10, 2015-01-14, 2015-01-15, 2015-01-16, 2015-01-17, 2015-01-18]

If you are not yet comfortable with lambdas and streams, you could of course write all this with conventional looping.

## Half-Open

Note that my results do not quite match yours. My code uses the commonly-used Half-Open approach to defining a span-of-time. In this approach, the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This allows spans of time to neatly abut one another without overlapping and without gaps. I suggest you too adopt this approach.

If you decline my advice, notice that `LocalDateTime` has alternate factory methods to use fully-closed approach where both the beginning and the ending are inclusive.

Answer (score 2):

My library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) offers direct support for the [subtraction of intervals](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IntervalCollection.html#minus-java.util.Collection-) according to your expectation A - (B + C + D).

```
ChronoFormatter<PlainTimestamp> parser = 
  ChronoFormatter.ofTimestampPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT);

// my assumption for your input, please adjust the interval pattern if necessary
String intervalPattern = "{0} / {1}";
String sa = "2015-01-01 00:00 / 2015-01-20 00:00";
String sb = "2015-01-05 00:00 / 2015-01-10 00:00"; 
String sc = "2015-01-11 00:00 / 2015-01-14 00:00";
String sd = "2015-01-19 00:00 / 2015-01-25 00:00";

TimestampInterval a = TimestampInterval.parse(sa, parser, intervalPattern);
TimestampInterval b = TimestampInterval.parse(sb, parser, intervalPattern);
TimestampInterval c = TimestampInterval.parse(sc, parser, intervalPattern);
TimestampInterval d = TimestampInterval.parse(sd, parser, intervalPattern);

IntervalCollection<PlainTimestamp> result = 
  IntervalCollection.onTimestampAxis().plus(a).minus(Arrays.asList(b, c, d));
```

The resulting interval collection contains the desired and expected intervals (just call `getIntervals()` on the result and `PlainTimestamp.toTemporalAccessor()` for conversion to `LocalDateTime`). All intervals here are by default half-open meaning that the start is inclusive but the end is exclusive. Therefore using the day numbers and a closed boundary char [ and an open boundary char ):

[1-5), [10-11), [14-19)

which almost matches your expectation "{1,2,3,4,10,15,16,17,18}" with the exception 14 instead of 15 (I think that is just a typo in your question).

Comment: Great creation. Let me check and get back to you.